# targeting same html elements in different id

Tags: html, css

How do I make lists and their items style differently when in article>div than in an artcicle>div>div ? I'm trying to not have to use !important. I'm trying to make the font size larger in an article... Below is the code I thought would work.

```
    article#home-left ul.list-arrows {
        margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
        font-size:4rem;
    }

    article ul.list-arrows {
        margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
        font-size:4rem;
    }

 <article>
    <ul>
      <li>Smaller font</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="home-left">
      <ul>
        <li>Largerfont</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

 </article>
```

Comment: None of your `ul`'s have the `list-arrows` class. And your `article` doesn't have and `id` of `#home-left`. And both of those CSS selectors apply identical styles ?

Comment: Im sorry - im using very general code.

Comment: I figured out my problem - i dont know if it's the right way but - I created global ul,li styles, then instead of trying to use the container to control the contents within, I just added a class name to the li tag within.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.

Your article doesn't have an ID of `#home-left`, the ID is attached to an ancestor of the article so, this

```
article#home-left ul li {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:4rem;
}
```

Should be this

```
article #home-left ul li {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:4rem;
}
```

There doesn't appear to be a class of `list-arrows` in your HTML so for the purposes of this answer I have ignored it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. Have you noticed that as SOON as you ask a question, you answer it yourself? I should make a site where you ask a question and nobody can answer it but yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ??

HTML

```
 <article>
    <ul class="list-arrows">
      <li>Smaller font</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="home-left">
      <ul class='list-arrows'>
        <li>Largerfont</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

 </article>
```

CSS

```
#home-left ul.list-arrows {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:4rem;
}

article ul.list-arrows {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:2rem;
}
```

FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/6yf8eno3/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <ul>
        <li class="list-arrows">Smaller font</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="home-left">
        <ul>
            <li class="list-arrows">Largerfont</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article ul .list-arrows {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:2rem;
}

#home-left ul .list-arrows {
    margin:1.5rem 0 2rem 3rem;
    font-size:4rem;
}
```